# Wordpress Owl Carousel Plugin Set Transition Delay Speed

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm using the Wordpress Owl carousel plugin by Pierre Jehan [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/owl-carousel/), but I cannot find a way to set the delay between slides changing.

I have tried lots of different option combinations from the Owl documentation without joy, including setting autoplay to false and trying to set timeout speed:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[owl-carousel category="hometop" autoplay="false" navigation="false" slideSpeed="15000" pagination="false" singleItem="true" autoplayTimeout="12000" ]'); ?>
```

Any help appreciated please

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error, I stumbled on a solution, which is not in the plugin docs and nowhere online, that I could find anyway.

I added autoplay="true" autoplay="12000" to the short-code, which gives me a 12 second delay between slides.

The full template short-code is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[owl-carousel category="hometop" autoplay="true" autoplay="12000" navigation="false" slideSpeed="15000" pagination="false" singleItem="true"]'); ?>
```